# Linq grouping not retrieving deep entities

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6

I am trying to use a Linq query on a football database using a grouping.  While the basic query essentially works, the child entities aren't loading properly.

I'm using Entity Framework 6 with SQL and Linq.

The database structure is as follows, each Season contains many Games and each game has a Referee, a home team and an away team.

An abstract representation of the database can be described as:

```
Season->ID
Season->List<Game> Games

Game->ID
Game->Season
Game->HomeTeam
Game->AwayTeam

Team->ID
Team->Name
```

My c# linq query is as follows:

```
var groupedGames = from game in Games        
    group game by game.Season
    into seasonGames
    orderby seasons.Key.ID
    select seasonGames;
```

This essentially groups games by season, however, when I interrogate the grouping using the code below, there is no reference to the Home or away team.

```
foreach(IGrouping<Season, Game> season in groupedGames)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Season:{0}", season.Year);

    foreach(Game game in season)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Home:{0}", game.HomeTeam.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("Away:{0}", game.AwayTeam.Name);
    }
}
```

When I access game.HomeTeam.Name I get a NullReferenceException.

I have set lazy loading to OFF, so I expect that I need to explicitly fetch the HomeTeam & AwayTeam from the Team tables.  Can I use an Include in this Linq query perhaps?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The query makes no sense. You can get the same information by simply querying `Seasons`.

Comment: You make a very good point.

Comment: So the question is do you really need that query. The problem is that `Include` is ignored in many types of queries.

Comment: Out of a fascination for understanding Linq better, it still troubles me that I can't make it work.  A query from the Season table would do, I guess I became fixated.

Comment: EF queries are not typical LINQ. In regular LINQ you are forced to `select` everything you need - no magically loaded properties.

Comment: @IvanStoev is right. Your query would work fine from a LINQ perspective. EF is awesome but it's also a killer like that. Your query is fine

Comment: If I switch lazy loading on, the query works fine.  I just don't see why I shouldn't be able to load it, particularly with an include, as it is working fine for other basic queries.  If it's a limitation of Linq, that the Include doesn't work with the Grouping, then I'll accept that.  Magically loading properties is the aim after all.

Comment: Lazy loading works outside of the LINQ query - when you first access a property of the returned object, and it executes behind the scenes additional db queries to get the data needed. While eager loading (`Include`) has to embed that additional data in your SQL query, which is not always possible.